# Проблема с кодировкой в Jar-файле

Tags: java

В приложении на `JavaFX` в таблицу считываю данные из текстового файла с кодировкой `UTF-8`.

Если запускаю проект из IDE (Eclipse) то в русские символы в таблице отображаются нормально, но если делаю экспорт приложения из IDE  в jar-файл и запускаю уже его, то вместо русских букв иероглифы. В чем может быть проблема?

В IDE кодировка стоит UTF-8:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может надо еще ее где-то прописывать?

Вот функция чтения файла:

```
public static List<Datacd> readFileIcd(String fileName) {
         List<Datacd> listDatacd = new ArrayList<>();
         DatacdreadDatacd;
         try(BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
             while (fileReader.ready()){
                 String[] strLine = fileReader.readLine().split(" &&& ");
                 readDataIcd = readLinecd(strLine);
                 if (readDatacd != null)
                     listDatacd.add(readDatacd);
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return listDatacd;
    }
```

Функция readLinecd раскидывает строку по параметрам класса Datacd, думаю ее нет смысла приводить

Comment: А как вы считываете файл?

Comment: я добавил код чтения из файла

Comment: Конструктор `FileReader` поддерживает 2 параметр `Charset`, попробуйте указать `StandardCharsets.UTF_8 `

Comment: помогло или нет?

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло